# Direct Keyboard Input from Linux Laptop to Windows PC

Tags: windows, keyboard

Every once in a while I sit with my laptop right in front of my desktop PC with the PC mouse next to it (which means I can still use it) but the keyboard is behind the laptop. It so happens I use both simultaneously. Now it is somewhat annoying to move the laptop aside to access the PC's keyboard. I was wondering if there is some kind of software which directs my keyboard input from the laptop at the press of a hotkey to my PC to control it.

I tried Google, but wasn't really sure what to search for. Many sites gave me standard remote control and such, which is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/?hl=nl).

> Combine your desktop devices together in to one cohesive experience. Synergy is software for sharing your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers on your desk. It works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.
>
> Synergy combines your devices together in to one cohesive experience.
>
> - Seamlessly move your mouse to any computer and start typing.
> - Works on all major operating systems (Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux).
> - Copy/paste between desktops
> - Drag and drop files from one computer to another (Windows and Mac OS X).
> - Network-based (IP) software KVM switch (non-video).